# How to configure mod-proxy-HTML without getting content encoding errors

Tags: apache-http-server

I have setup a reverse proxy on my workplace LAN so several sites can be accessed from outside our LAN. I have included the mod-proxy-HTML, so it handles the rewriting of URLs in the returned HTML.

However Firefox and Chromium complains about an encoding problem.

If I edit the `network.http.accept-encoding` option of Firefox and remove the default `gzip;deflate`; then the site looks ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Configuring Apache like this:

```
SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
```

solved my problem.

Comment: I had to uncomment `LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so` in my httpd.conf file in order to make this work for me.

Comment: This resulted in proxy-html running twice for me, resulting in url maps for / adding the app path twice - for me the answer was `SetOutputFilter INFLATE;DEFLATE` - as per http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies "note that ProxyHTMLEnable correctly inserts the proxy-html filter between INFLATE and DEFLATE"

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling `mod_deflate` in your Apache configuration.

Comment: That would do. However, I make SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

**ProxyHTMLCharsetOut ***

*ProxyHTMLCharsetOut
    Syntax ProxyHTMLCharsetOut name
    This selects an encoding for mod_proxy_html output. It should not normally be used, as any change from the default UTF-8 (Unicode - as used internally by libxml2) will impose an additional processing overhead. The special token ProxyHTMLCharsetOut * will generate output using the same encoding as the input.*